# 18 families and 6 plays

Tags: combinatorics

I have to organize a meeting with 18 families. Each family has to play 6 plays. For each play 3 families meet.

How can I combine them, so they always meet different families?

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible; even a simpler variation with 12 families and 2 families per play is impossible. This is known as the [Thirty-six officers problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thirty-six_officers_problem).

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you had 12 people and 4 rounds and 4 groups.  You could accomplish this through the use of orthogonal latin squares!

Here are 3 mutually orthogonal latin squares of order 4.

```
A B C D    E F G H    I J K L
B A D C    G H E F    L K J I
C D A B    H G F E    J I L K 
D C B A    F E H G    K L I J
```

Lets superimpose them:

```
AEI  BFJ  CGK  DHL
BGL  AHK  DEJ  CFI
CHJ  DGI  AFL  BEK
DFK  CEL  BHI  AGJ
```

You will notice that if these become our groupings, then if you take any one group (say A), and look at its partners, you will never see a duplicate.  A plays with E and I in the first round, H and K in the second, F and L in the third, and G and J in the forth.

This satisfies your requirement!!

So all you need to do is find 3 mutually orthogonal latin squares of order 6!

However, this is mathematically impossible.